# I have problem with Datepicker context (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, datepicker

i have problem with `DatePickerDialog` i want to choose the context for it but i dont know i tried v for view on my class but it did not work i also tried `getContext()` and did not work

```
 @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
   DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
   context here1 ?,
   android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
   null,year,
   month[0],day);

   datePickerDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
   datePickerDialog.show();
 }
```

[see error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apbsH.png)

Comment: if you are showing `DatePickerDialog` in fragment then try `getActivity()` for context

Comment: thank you very much it did work but why can you explane it ?

Comment: sure, had added this as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are showing `DatePickerDialog` in fragment then pass `getActivity()` for `context`
as `getActivity()` returns the activity associated with a fragment and activity is a context (since Activity extends Context).

and if you are showing `DatePickerDialog` in Activity then pass `YourActivty.this`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using min-sdk <24 then you need to annotate method with @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N) as its available since Android N. If you want to support older versions then use another constructor supported from API 1.

```
DatePickerDialog b = new DatePickerDialog(TestActivity.this,
                    android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth,
                    null,
                    2020,
                    10,
                    16);
```

[Refer this API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int))

As you have declared inside onClick listener use `ActivityName.this` as context